# How to read and store in memory each line of file using syscalls in C

Tags: c, system-calls

Im trying to read each line from a file, and store those values in a pointer array. Im new to C so sorry for my scrappy code.

I tried reading char by char, put them in a string, and then "store" that string in the pointer array, since it looked like a simple solution, but im having trouble with memory allocations.

Here is my code:

```
char *files[100];
char buffer;

int r, i, j;
char temp[100];

int fd=open(argv[1], O_RDONLY);

i=j=0;
```

```
 while(read (fd, &buffer, 1) > 0) {
        
        if(buffer != '\n') {
            temp[i] = buffer;
        }
        else{
           
            files[j]=temp;
            j++;
            i=0;

            continue;
            
        }
        i++;

    }
```

Comment: Did someone tell you you had to use system calls? `read(fd, &c, 1)` is a terrible and totally disrecommended way of reading a file.

Comment: Are you required to handle arbitrarily many lines?  Of arbitrary length?  Or can you assume that there will be no more than (say) 100 lines, each of at most 100 characters long?

Comment: I must use system calls, i can´t even use functions like the string.h library, or fread, etc.....

Comment: The files have thousands of lines, I then must use the the syscall fork() to create more sub process to search a specific string in the file

Comment: Before worrying about reading, check if the call to ```open``` succeeded. You may alternatively want to read the whole file into a dynamically allocated buffer (reallocating if needed), and then parse it into null-terminated strings.

Comment: I added a check to see if the open succed. The only erros I get are segmentation errors with my array of pointers. Even tho the temp variable hold the current line, when i equal this to the files[j], it just doesnt work.

Comment: Kindly edit the question to include those errors. You also do not null-terminate the strings and the array of pointers isn't pointing to any valid location. You need to allocate space for them. Note that ```=``` only exchanges pointers.

Comment: The code only uses one buffer `temp[]` to load with input characters. All the pointers `files[]` will be pointing to this single buffer... You need to find out about dynamic memory allocation like malloc()` (and `realloc()` for a growing array of pointers.)

Comment: yes, that the problem. been doing some reaserch and what you said is my problem () they all point to the same buffer. I dont know how to use malloc. can someone explain ? thank you all

Comment: If you're only allowed to use low-level system calls, are you even allowed to call `malloc`?

Comment: Yes, I can use malloc, just can't use functions to manipulate strings and files. Basically just malloc

Answer (score 0):

I had to allocate memory for each line, otherwise, my `files` vector always pointed to the same buffer. I just added the following line before attributing the value of `temp` to `files`:

```
files[j] = (char*) malloc (size of (char) * strlen(temp);
```

Comment: Please, note that casting ```malloc```'s output is not needed at all. You can just use ```files[j] = malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(temp));```. Additionally, it would be advisable to check whether ```malloc``` returned a ```NULL``` pointer (failed allocation).